# How to keep certain files exempt from .htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-403

I have one website (www.mysite.com) that I have on a temporary redirect to another folder (www.mysite.com/tempfolder/index.php). I also host another site in the root folder of www.mysite.com called www.subsite.com. It has it's own URL, but I can't figure out how to make that entire sub-folder exempt from the redirect! Any ideas? Here is what my .htaccess file looks like right now (which is perfectly redirecting everything to the temporary landing page).

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from ***
 allow from ****
 allow from *****
</LIMIT>
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mysite.com.com/tempfolder/index.php
<filesMatch ".(htm|html|php|css|js|php|gif|jpg|db|png)$">
 order allow,deny
 allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas? thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

try putting an .htaccess file in the subfolder that does not contain the redirection rules. That should work just fine -- it can even be a blank file.

Comment: There is one. It's a wordpress site (the subfolder), so they have their own format. Good idea, though.